# Laravel Feature test can't make a DELETE request

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm using Laravel 5.4

**web.php**

```
Route::delete('claim/{id?}', 'ClaimController@claimRemove');
```

**myTest.php**

```
$response = $this->json('delete', 'claim', [
   'id' => $id
]);
```

When i run phpunit, i'm getting the

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

BUT if I run it via Postman or phpstorm rest client - it works fine, so the reason is somewhere in `$this->json` method. I also tried `$this->call`.
If I switch delete method to post in web.php and in my test file - test is passing well.
So, question is - why it's not working with DELETE method or how to test DELETE calls?:)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it was version issue. Didn't modify anything, but after two weeks just `composer update` and test passed fine.

Answer (score 0):

If `composer update` simply solved your problem it sounds like that your route cache has not been updated with your latest route changes. Both `composer update` and `composer install` include normally a list of artisan commands such as `route:clear` as they are specified indirectly in the composer.json file when `optimize` is used.

Secondly, use this form below due to the fact the id is part of your route otherwise it will hit the route without an id. However it will also be acceptable because you have made the parameter optional.

```
$response = $this->json('delete', 'claim/' . $id, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you have defined your routes, the ID needs to be passed in the URL.

Replace

```
$response = $this->json('delete', 'claim', [
  'id' => $id
]);
```

with

```
$response = $this->json('delete', 'claim/' . $id, []);
```

Comment: that's the different one ID (actually I renamed it to simplify before ask), sorry for making delusion. By the way, it's not working on a different level.